# Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Error'

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

I'm using Angular 2 and passing an Error from an HTTP request into the `logAndPassOn` method.  I am getting the error "Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Error'."  The typeof Error is object but it seems like a typeof Error would be recognized like a typeof File is.

```
  private logAndPassOn (error: Error) {
    if (error.status == 403) {
      Do things
    }
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
```

I got around this by setting the error's type as 'any' but it seems there should be a better way.  Is there a library to import typeof Error?  Is there a way to handle this besides writing my own Error class and importing it?

Comment: Not sure where this method is used, but If you are working with the Http observable and this is your error callback, I think the actual type passed to the error callback is `Response` from `@angular/http`, the same response you get in the success callback,  not an `Error`.

Comment: I am using Http observable and this is my error callback, but if I change Error to Response or response I get "Cannot find name 'Response'."

Comment: You need to import it from `@angular/http`

Comment: Importing Response and making the error type Response worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object passed to the `Http` error callback is actually of type `Response` from the `@angular/http` module. This is the same `Response` you would get from the initial Http call. If there is an error response, then the `Response` get sent as the error through to the subscriber.

```
import { Response } from '@angular/json';

http.get(..)
    .subscribe(
         (res: Response) => { doSomething(res.json()) }
         (res: Response) => { ... });
```

So basically, your trying to use `Error` is not correct. It works when you use `any`, as during runtime the actual `Response` object passed, *does* have a `status` property.